# Method Range of Object Worksheet failed excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have been stuck on a particular problem I am having with an excel visual basic macro. 
I have written a script to simply paste a dynamic range of data from one worksheet to the other, The sheet that is being pasted to is a running sheet that updates to the next empty row each time new data is sent to it. 
For certain ranges of data my code breaks and gives me the 1004 error.
I have looked at multiple similar questions and they don't seem to have given me any solutions.

I will first post my code then a data set that works and a data set that does not.

```
Private Sub RunningSheetClick_Click()

Dim lastrow As Long

Dim Vals As Range

Dim copyWS As Worksheet
Dim pasteWS As Worksheet

Set pasteWS = Sheets("Full List")
Set copyWS = Sheets("Macro Test")
Setlastrow = Sheets("Full List").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

copyWS.Activate

' the following line is where my error appears
Set Vals = copyWS.Range("B3:S" & copyWS.Range("B3").End(xlDown))

Vals.Select

Vals.Copy _
    Destination:=pasteWS.Range("A" & lastrow)

End Sub
```

[This is a data set that works and exports correctly to the sheet "Full List"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTW3P.png)

[This is a data set that does not, I believe it has to do with column B and the strings that are in those cells as compared to the integers in the first data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdDof.png)

Any help would be appreciated, thank you for taking the time

Comment: It always seems too much to ask to a)  see the row and column identifiers so we can make sense of the code b) know what line the error occurs on.

Comment: Put option explicit at the top of your code and declare all variables

Comment: And this typo is wrong and possibly could have been an error Setlastrow    .... If you had Set lastrow. lastRow is a Long so no Set keyoword. That is for objects. Without declaring all your variables I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bad syntax that should never work. You just cannot concatenate a range object onto a string and expect a valid range object. I suspect it works with numbers since `copyWS.Range("B3").End(xlDown)` is returning its cell value by default. So if the value at the bottom of column B was 99, you would be resolved to `Range("B3:S99")`.

```
Set Vals = copyWS.Range("B3:S" & copyWS.Range("B3").End(xlDown))
```

It should be something like,

```
with copyWS
    Set Vals = .Range(.cells(3, "B"),  .cells(rows.count, "B").end(xlup).offset(0, 17))
end with
```

Comment: That fixed my problem, for some reason my syntax did work for some cases, though I haven't touched visual basic in a couple years so I've been rusty. Could you mind explaining what was bad about my syntax?
Thanks again

Comment: Also why is the offset (0,17) ??

Comment: Because column S is 17 columns to the right of column B.

Comment: thank you for your explanation that helped a lot, I was curious as to why having letters in those cells of column B was breaking it. 
and yes S is 17 duh, sorry for overlooking that haha.

Anyway it is working for me now thank you so much for your help!